# Insert into one query (string) into many tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have a small problem with php, mysql and query:

These are my queries:

`insert into schedule (rowid, parentrowid, sortIndexProj, sortindex, projectnummer, recordtype, refrecid, description, specialrow) values (451,451,0,1,243,10,243,"",0),(494,451,0,2,243,70,17,"",0);`

`insert into scheduleevent (rowid, refrowid, fromdate, todate, description) values (533,451,"2016-04-06 00:00:00","2016-04-07 00:00:00","Start week 14 t/m 40 Hoofdleidingen gereed week 24"),(571,451,"2016-03-29 00:00:00","2016-03-30 00:00:00","BAM-EDU transport")`

`insert into scheduleevent (rowid, refrowid, fromdate, todate, description) values (702,494,"2016-03-10 00:00:00","2016-03-11 00:00:00","Moni(cz)ka")`

I want to execute this query using mysql_query(). But after execute mysql_error() return this error

> Something is wrong in your syntax obok 'insert into scheduleevent (rowid, refrowid, fromdate, todate, description) value' w linii 1

When i try execute this query into phpmyadmin everything is OK.
I'm confused, please help me.

Comment: try using `mysqli` - notably `mysqli_multi_query`

Answer (score 0):

Use the following syntax:

```
INSERT ALL
  INTO mytable (column1, column2, column_n) VALUES (expr1, expr2, expr_n)
  INTO mytable (column1, column2, column_n) VALUES (expr1, expr2, expr_n)
  INTO mytable (column1, column2, column_n) VALUES (expr1, expr2, expr_n)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a semicolon to your second query and try it:

```
INSERT INTO scheduleevent (
    rowid,
    refrowid,
    fromdate,
    todate,
    description
) values (
    533,
    451,
    "2016-04-06 00:00:00",
    "2016-04-07 00:00:00",
    "Start week 14 t/m 40 Hoofdleidingen gereed week 24"
),(
    571,
    451,
    "2016-03-29 00:00:00",
    "2016-03-30 00:00:00",
    "BAM-EDU transport"
);
```